# problems with my search module on my website

Tags: php, mysql, search, pdo

I'm having some problems with my search module on my website. I'm using this code:

```
    if(!isset($_POST['search'])) {
$query = "SELECT id, title FROM cars ORDER BY id LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";
}
if(isset($_POST['search']) && $_POST['categories'] != "all") {
$query = "SELECT id, title FROM cars WHERE title LIKE CONCAT(?, '%') ESCAPE '+'  AND category = ? ORDER BY id LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";
}
if(isset($_POST['search']) && $_POST['categories'] == "all") {
$query = "SELECT id, title FROM cars WHERE title LIKE CONCAT(?, '%') ESCAPE '+' ORDER BY id LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";
}
try { 
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    if(!isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $stmt->bindValue(1, (int) $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(2, (int) $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }
    if(isset($_POST['search']) && $_POST['categories'] != "all") {
        $search= str_replace(array('+', '%', '_'), array('++', '+%', '+_'), $_POST['search']);
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(2, (int) $_POST['categories'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(3, (int) $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(4, (int) $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }
    if(isset($_POST['search']) && $_POST['categories'] == "all") {
        $search= str_replace(array('+', '%', '_'), array('++', '+%', '+_'), $_POST['search']);
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(2, (int) $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(3, (int) $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }
    $stmt->execute(); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) { 
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 
$cars = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

My search form looks like this:

```
<input name="search" type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" />
<select name="categories">
    <option value="all">All Categories</option>
    <option value="1">Free</option>
    <option value="2">In use</option>
    <option value="3">Damaged</option>
</select>
```

In cars table, each title look like this: 2009 Porsche 911 (year make model)
When I search, if I don't fill in search box, it works ok, it works ok even when I search for 2009, but if search for Porsche, I get no results. Why is that? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Note, shorthand for `limit ? offset ?` would be `limit ?,?`. I prefer it but personal preference :)

Comment: I would look in the str_replace code. maybe you can var_dump the result of it  and get a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONCAT(?, '%')` means that you search for words who start by the search-word .

so 2009 is the first word thats why it return . if you want get the second word try using this

```
    CONCAT('%',?, '%')
```

or just like that

```
    CONCAT("'",?, "'")
```

Comment: values from <select name="categories"> are integers, If I search for Porsche and leave <option value="all">All Categories</option> selected, $stmt->bindValue(2, (int) $_POST['categories'], PDO::PARAM_INT); doesn't apply

Comment: using CONCAT('%',?, '%') works, thank you. Another question is how safe is my code as it is now?

Comment: until it is finished , I prefer to use `catch`